# Axiom of replacement vs. Axiom of separation and Galileo paradox

Tags: set-theory, paradoxes

Galileo's paradox says that on one side there are fewer square numbers (second powers) among natural numbers than all numbers because only some numbers are squares. On the other side, there are as many squares as numbers because every square has its root and every number has its square.

There are two ways to construct the set of all squares of natural numbers in ZF.

1. According to the axiom of specification, we consider the set $A = \{n \in \mathbb N, (\exists m)(m \in \mathbb N) \wedge n = m^2\}$.
2. According to the replacement schema, if we use a function $F(x) = x^2$ we get the set $B = \{n^2, n \in \mathbb N\}$.

It seems that $A$ is a proper subset of natural numbers $A \subset \mathbb N$.

$B$ is an image of natural numbers, $B = F(A)$ but is $B \subseteq \mathbb N$?

Finally, is $A = B$?

Comment: Yes, $A=B$, and each is a proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$ which nonetheless has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$ (Galileo's "paradox" is only a paradox if you insist on intuitions about finite sets carrying over to infinite ones).

Comment: How can we prove it?

Answer (score 1):

What a good question and clever use of 1 & 2 to try to represent the two Galileo statements.

To answer your comment, both your definitions A & B are actually the same, and represent the same set {$n^2 : n \in N$}. This is because in A there is "$n=m^2$", so n has to be a square number.

The Galileo statement that there are fewer squares than numbers, or "there is a non empty set of numbers in N that are not squares" (which I think was the intention of A), is in set notation given by:

$ \text{ Set of numbers that are not squares is not empty (A)} \iff N \text{ \ } B \neq \emptyset$

$\text{..................................................................................} \iff $ { $2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,..... $}$\neq \emptyset$